How to talk about the “shape” of the kernel of an integral transform
So I'm learning about integral transforms, and although it isn't a complete specification, the fact that the Fourier transform decomposes functions into sinusoids, the Laplace into damped sinusoids, the wavelet into wavelets, etc., gives you a basic idea of what each is about. But what are you actually meant to call this set of functions of t that comes out of the Kernel of a transform? If I was talking to computer scientists, I could say something like “the (real or imaginary component of the) image of $\texttt{curry}\ \texttt{flip}\ K$” but I don't think engineers would like that.
As a side question, are there any distinct integral transforms with unique utility for which this set of functions is the same?

basis functions?
